# How to add expand and collapse images on div in xslt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xslt

I created some dynamic divs with some data now all divs are expand and collapse perfectly.Now how to add expand and collapse images on div.I'm new to designing in **xslt**.

```
<xsl:template match="category[key!='org.model.Category.uncategorized']">
<xsl:param name="cont"/>
<xsl:if test="$cont != 'true'">
 <xsl:variable name="key" select="key"/>
 <li>
 <div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="subDiv">
   <a href="#"   onClick="collapseList(document.getElementById('{generate-id()}'))">
        <span>
            <xsl:value-of select="$key"/>
        </span>
    </a>                
    </div>
    <div class="childsubDiv" id="{generate-id()}" >
    <ul id="subMenu" class="subMenu">
        <xsl:for-each select="pages/page">
         <xsl:sort select="@order" data-type="number"/>
             <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
             <xsl:with-param name="cont" select="$cont"/>
             </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</li>
</xsl:if>      
</xsl:template>
```

javascript code here:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<xsl:text>
    function collapseList(element){
    element.style.display = element.style.display == 'none' ? '' :   'none';
    }
</xsl:text>
```

Comment: I don't see any `img` elements in there, nor any CSS background images, so you will need to show where you want an image and whether you want to remove it or change its referenced source.

Comment: @Martin Honnen :i want image on anchor tag div **<div class="subDiv">** how to add css file and how to get images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your XSLT also generates a HTML 'head`element where you can insert CSS (either inline with the`style`element or external with a`link` element) you can add CSS alike

```
<style>
a.expander span::before { content: " - "; font-size: 120%; }
a.expander.collapsed span::before { content: " + "; font-size: 120%;}
</style>
```

and then change the template you have to

```
<xsl:template match="category[key!='org.model.Category.uncategorized']">
<xsl:param name="cont"/>
<xsl:if test="$cont != 'true'">
 <xsl:variable name="key" select="key"/>
 <li>
 <div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="subDiv">
   <a href="#" class="expander"  onclick="collapseList(document.getElementById('{generate-id()}')); this.classList.toggle('collapsed');">
        <span>
            <xsl:value-of select="$key"/>
        </span>
    </a>                
    </div>
    <div class="childsubDiv" id="{generate-id()}" >
    <ul id="subMenu" class="subMenu">
        <xsl:for-each select="pages/page">
         <xsl:sort select="@order" data-type="number"/>
             <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
             <xsl:with-param name="cont" select="$cont"/>
             </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</li>
</xsl:if>      
</xsl:template>
```

With that example I have simply inserted characters, if you want to use images instead then change the CSS to say e.g.

```
<style>
a.expander span::before { content: url(minus.gif); }
a.expander.collapsed span::before { content: url(plus.gif); }
</style>
```

Comment: i have one problem initially it starts with expanding,but i want collapse where to change code

Comment: Well then generate `<a href="#" class="expander collapsed"  onclick="collapseList(document.getElementById('{generate-id()}')); this.classList.toggle('collapsed');">
        <span>` and `<div class="childsubDiv" id="{generate-id()}"  style="display: none;">`